# Open Link on Twitter App IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, twitter, mailchimp

I have created a mail template on mailchimp. It consists of a twitter link. But an IPad or an IPhone user clicks on the link from his/her mail, the twitter link opens in the browser instead of the twitter app.

This does not happen in Android.

Any workarounds?

Comment: If you tried using twitters app scheme for urls then it wouldn't work for desktop devices. Twitter should handle redirecting the user to the app. Shame on them! I believe there is a link that appears at the top of the page in the browser that allows the user to open it in Twitter

Comment: That's probably your best bet unless you want to create a custom web page that redirects certain devices to different links.

Comment: @DanielStorm he can't or else he would loose compatibility with other devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a custom URL `<a href="twitter://"` than other Android/Desktop devices won't be able to open it. Twitter doesn't redirect with standard URLs from Safari and they should. But they do offer a "Open in app" button at the top left.

So if you want you could add two buttons in the email. One specifically for iOS: `twitter://status?id=373205208664272897` and one for other devices `https://twitter.com/support/status/373205208664272897`.

Or you could create a site that reads the user agent of the device than determines which URL to redirect to.

The third option is just leaving it alone given that it's not really such a big issue in the grand scheme.

Comment: I am going to try the first option.

Comment: Ok. Not sure how you have the status IDs stored. But you'll have to write out each URL manually I would think

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *stringURL = @"twitter://";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

From [iPhone URL Schemes](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Twitter).

Comment: @kdogisthebest oops. Totally read that question incorrectly. Using `twitter://` in Safari does indeed open the Twitter application though. Perhaps using deep linking to check if the link is opened on an iOS device and then building on `twitter://` could achieve the desired result.

Comment: well mailchimp does not allow you to write custom scripts. all that I have to do is to create links which will open in the application